# regarding a callback function of request.addListener

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coming from a Java background and I a way to make use of incoming data to a node.js server:

```
request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
  postData += postDataChunk;
  console.log("Received POST data chunk '"+
  postDataChunk + "'.");
});
```

as I have seen the postData variable is allways receiving new data and adds it to the existing.
My question is:
every time the data event is occuring the callback function is executed, but in the way I see it, every new time the function is being called we are actually getting a new variable "postData". So I do not understand how exactlly the postData variable is actually being updated every time and not being created as a new variable as it would have been in regular Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use var `postData`, it would do the same as it would in JAVA but here `postData` is a global variable that gets incremented. In JavaScript, if you don't explicitly write the keyword `var`, the variable is automatically instantiated on first call and then used as if it was a global variable.

Hopefully, the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) would make things clear.

**EXAMPLE**
What  you wrote is essentially;

```js
request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
  /*"var" omitted in function!
   *creates variable "window['postData']"
   *unless already created*/
  postData += postDataChunk;
  console.log("Received POST data chunk '"+
  postDataChunk + "'.");
});
```

Scoping to the function using `var`

```js
request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
  //"var" keyword used! variable created in this scope!
  var postData += postDataChunk;
  console.log("Received POST data chunk '"+
  postDataChunk + "'.");
});
```

Comment: i can't figure how to do that . i am new sorry

Comment: that's ok, @user2625270, just click the tick in between the up and down arrows to the top-left of the answer